# Make token metadata immutable with SPL-TOKEN

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, metadata, spl-token-cli

Tech Stack:
Solana CLI / SPL-TOKEN
Ubuntu 18

---

### Token vs Token-2022 Program

I am using the CLI SPL-TOKEN cargo package, I am not a rust user, nor a javascript user, so my access level into the solana blockchain is somewhat limited...

---

What I want to do:
On markets like 'BIRDEYE' etc, my token has this option X'd out:
[image: BIRDEYE.SO/TOKEN/x]

### The description of 'Mutable Info': ***The token information such as name, logo, website address can be changed by the owner.***

How I've tried to do this previously:

I simply haven't, I've researched it, however, nothing really details the CLI to this degree.

Please let me know, I will be checking this thread every hour for a solution, or else solana might not be the best choice for my goals.

Comment: cab you let me know how did u check the first one the mintable one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your token have any meta data assigned to it already? If not it probably shows as mutable.

If you create meta data for your token (Icon and name etc) you can set it to mutable = false afterwards. Then it will probably also show as not mutable on birdeye.

Here is a nice open source example showing you how:
https://github.com/loopcreativeandy/video-tutorial-resources/blob/main/metadataUpdate/mpl_metadata.ts

Comment: I appreciate your assistance, with some basic programming knowledge, I was able to reconstruct the script and allow it to work for me, you have honestly helped me more then you know.